# Can I combine Mythic Contingency with Mythic Limited Wish

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, wish, mythic-adventures

[Mythic Contingency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contingency/)'s duration is 1day/level and (not using the Augmented Version) I cast 1+half your tier's companion spells on it.

With [Mythic Wish](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/mythicAdventures/mythicSpells/limitedWish.html) I can duplicate a mythic spell I know.

The description of Contingency says:

> You can use only one contingency spell at a time; if a second is cast,
>   the first one (if still active) is dispelled.

But I do not cast another contingency spell, I cast a Limited Wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes.

When casting on yourself, that condition is completely removed on the Mythic version of the spell.

> The target can have only one contingency spell upon it at a time **unless it also knows mythic contingency**.

Meaning that you can cast as many *Mythic Contingencies* on yourself as you *wish*, limited only by your *Mythic Tier*.

> The number of companion spells you can have on yourself is equal to **1 + half your tier**.